# Encode bitmaps from a view into video with MediaRecorder

Tags: java, android, bitmap, mediarecorder, surface

I have been trying to encode bitmap images from a view into a mp4 video. I am using MediaRecorder setup with Surface as input. The code is failing on the second iteration in the loop. It appears that the canvas is not successfully unlocked, and then lockCanvas fails and throws an error.

What could be causing this exception?

```
public class ViewRecorder
{
    private View recordView;
    private boolean run = true;
    private String filename;

    public ViewRecorder(View recordView, String filename)
    {
        this.recordView = recordView;
        this.filename = filename;

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Task());
        thread.start();
    }

    /*
     * Stops the recording
     */
    public void Stop()
    {
        this.run = false;
    }

    /*
     * Encodes a frame every 100 mS
     */
    private class Task implements Runnable
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                MediaRecorder mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
                mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
                mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
                mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(10);
                //this.mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(20000);
                mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
                mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(filename + ".mp4");

                recordView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(recordView.getDrawingCache());
                recordView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

                mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

                mediaRecorder.prepare();
                mediaRecorder.start();   // Recording is now started

                while(run)
                {
                    Thread.sleep(100);

                    recordView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(recordView.getDrawingCache());
                    recordView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

                    Surface surface = mediaRecorder.getSurface();
                    Canvas canvas = surface.lockCanvas(null);
                    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, new Paint());
                    surface.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }

                mediaRecorder.stop();
                mediaRecorder.reset();
                mediaRecorder.release();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the exception:

```
11-21 18:59:35.220 26737-27432/ W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
11-21 18:59:35.220 26737-27432/ W/System.err:     at android.view.Surface.nativeLockCanvas(Native Method)
11-21 18:59:35.220 26737-27432/ W/System.err:     at android.view.Surface.lockCanvas(Surface.java:322)
11-21 18:59:35.221 26737-27432/ W/System.err:     at .ViewRecorder$Task.run(ViewRecorder.java:77)
11-21 18:59:35.221 26737-27432/ W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
11-21 19:00:47.783 26737-26744/ W/art: Suspending all threads took: 35.361ms
11-21 19:01:25.983 26737-26744/ W/art: Suspending all threads took: 22.830ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're still after a solution but I found this:

Move - Surface surface = mediaRecorder.getSurface();

outside of the loop so it's only called once. Errors on the second time it's called